# Date Time format according to culture in MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my code which converts a datetime to a particular format i.e MM/dd/yyyy (culture:"en-us")

```
convert(varchar(max),getdate(),101)
```

I want to convert the datetime into a format depending on culture.
For Example,

(1)Date format of **Danish culture** is dd-MM-YYYY (da-dk)

(2)Date format of **German culture** is dd.MM.yyyy (de-de)

How can i acheive this in MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Unless the user is directly entering queries in management studio and inspecting the results there, there's almost certainly a better place to convert from datetime data into strings - somewhere closer to the user and further away from the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),105),CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),104)
```

this also works for me...

```
select convert(varchar,DATENAME(DAY,GETDATE()))+'-'+convert(varchar,MONTH(getdate()))+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,year(getdate()))
```

this is for "DD-MM-YYYY" format and its working in 2008 R2

```
select convert(varchar,DATENAME(DAY,GETDATE()))+'.'+convert(varchar,MONTH(getdate()))+'.'+CONVERT(varchar,year(getdate()))
```

This is for "DD.MM.YYYY" As of my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge it is possible to get date and time as per culture defined, only after SQL Server 2012 and above. But below it we can achieve it by making a custom function where as per culture return the date and time in required format.